# Pages displays as Restricted to Admin

Tags: permissions

I have converted multisite to normal WordPress site, but when i tried to edit pages from the admin backend, i didn't get the edit icon to edit the pages only view icon display on hover.

That is because of permission issue, but i logged in through administrator account. I checked through the database as well and seems i have the correct permission! 
[image]

Can't figure out what is the actually problem, it would be great if someone help me to solve this.

This is what i getting when i go to edit the pages: [image]

Comment: That looks like a plugin restricting things. Haven't seen the red "restricted" wording in Core. I'd deactivate plugins and try a default theme, then one by one turn things back on to identify - or look for any role plugins.

Comment: @WebElaine, tried but not helpful

Comment: Try adding User Role Editor. Add a new user for yourself with an alternate role - say Editor - then with URE make sure all the "pages" permissions (edit_pages, edit_others_pages, edit_published_pages, etc. etc.) are enabled.